# Decode huge amount of data encoded in base64 in c ++

Tags: c++, base64

I have a string type variable of 1,801,048 characters encoded in base64 and I want to decode them. I have this snippet that worked well with shorter strings, however when I put the 1,801,048 data it causes errors.

This is the Snippet:

```
static inline bool is_base64(unsigned char c) 
{
    return (isalnum(c) || (c == '+') || (c == '/'));
}

string base64_decode(string const& encoded_string) 
{
    int in_len = encoded_string.size();
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int in_ = 0;
    unsigned char char_array_4[4], char_array_3[3];
    string ret;

    while (in_len-- && ( encoded_string[in_] != '=') && is_base64(encoded_string[in_])) 
    {
        char_array_4[i++] = encoded_string[in_]; in_++;

        if (i ==4) 
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                char_array_4[i] = base64_chars.find(char_array_4[i]);
            }

            char_array_3[0] = (char_array_4[0] << 2) + ((char_array_4[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
            char_array_3[1] = ((char_array_4[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
            char_array_3[2] = ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3) << 6) + char_array_4[3];

            for (i = 0; (i < 3); i++)
            {
                ret += char_array_3[i];
            }

            i = 0;
        }
    }

    if (i) 
    {
        for (j = i; j < 4; j++)
        {
            char_array_4[j] = 0;
        }

        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            char_array_4[j] = base64_chars.find(char_array_4[j]);
        }

        char_array_3[0] = (char_array_4[0] << 2) + ((char_array_4[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
        char_array_3[1] = ((char_array_4[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
        char_array_3[2] = ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3) << 6) + char_array_4[3];

        for (j = 0; (j < i - 1); j++)
        {
            ret += char_array_3[j];
        }   
    }

    return ret;
}
```

This is how I use it, but it causes the program to close or there is a memory overflow (I think I'm not sure):

```
string base64_encoded_data = "UEsDBBQAAAAIAI1Wp0xrN4dXHwIAA...." //Size = 1,801,048
string base64_decoded_data = base64_decode(base64_encoded_data);
```

Where is the error or how can I improve the program so that the decoficiation happens correctly? The input and output of data must be of the string type.

Comment: What is the error message? Can you run it in Debug mode?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe i cant see the error cause i am running the program in an electronic device (POS) and it has no debbug mode. Thats why i am asuming it has a memory overflow.

Comment: The device capabilities might well be important enough to include in the question. I'd suggest you edit it with that information.

Comment: Any way for you to export the failing string to a file you can run through your code under a more debugger-friendly environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely with how you are constructing the return string `ret`.  You're adding one character at a time, so the string will grow capacity periodically.  Because of the size of the blocks that are allocated and how the heap works, this will leave a lot of unallocated but still used heap space.

Since you can compute the size required for your returned string, you can use

```
ret.reserve((in_len * 3 + 3) / 4);
```

before your `while` loop to allocate one buffer big enough for the entire string.  This will avoid all the additional memory allocations and should allow your to decode your large strings.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a custom device, maybe you trying to store more than are common string can store. Strings have a maximum size ([you can see here how to check](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/max_size/)). You should check if it fits your use case, if not maybe use a buffer. If the size is fine, more information is needed.

Comment: Since the source `encoded_string` parameter is a `string`, and will have more characters than the decoded string, this is not the problem.